# Nginx rewrite with id in location

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to write a string in nginx config which redirects `/user1.html` to `/user/1-/`. Sure, ID should be like ([0-9]+). Donno why I can't.

If I write without regexp `rewrite ^/user1.html$ /user/1-/ last;`, everything fine. But when I add regexp (`rewrite ^/user([0-9]+)\.html$ /user/$1-/ last;`), nginx gives me 404.

I also tried to write `(.*)` except of `([0-9]+)`, but nothing changed.

I also tried to write a special location for that - also without any result.

Help me please...

complete config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/localhost/;
    index index.php;
    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
        return 301 $1;
    }
    location / {
        rewrite ^/user([0-9]+)\.html$ /user/\1-/ last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `\1` instead of `$1` like `/user/\1-/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `rewrite ^/user([0-9]+)\.html$ /user/\1-/ last;`? still 404

Comment: Show complete config

Comment: @AlexeyTen added the current one to first post.

Comment: First, return `$1` instead of `\1`. Second, what exactly does not work? Why do you think that nginx returns 404, not your PHP application?

Comment: @AlexeyTen First of all, because I tried only those links which exists. If i write `/user/1-/` manually, everything goes fine. Then, url in browser is not changing.

Comment: Does request gets to PHP? What actual params PHP gets?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Got it from debug log. /index.php?/user/1-/ also works with browser.
`2015/02/09 19:21:05 [debug] 7430#0: *16 http run request: "/index.php?/user/1-/"` `2015/02/09 19:21:05 [debug] 7430#0: *16 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/index.php"` `2015/02/09 19:21:05 [debug] 7430#0: *16 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`